# Why does calling super in Groovy (version 2.4.5) miss the parent class?

Tags: groovy

Given the following arrangement of classes:

```
class GrandParent { 
    String init() { 
        return "GrandParent init, " 
    } 
}

class Parent extends GrandParent { 
    String init() { 
        return super.init() + "Parent init, " 
    } 
}

class ChildInitAndVisit extends Parent { 
    String init() { 
        return super.init() + "Child init" 
    }

    String visit() { 
        return super.init() + "Child visit" 
    } 
}

class ChildVisitOnly extends Parent { 
    String visit() { 
        return super.init() + "Child visit" 
    } 
}
```

and then using them in this way:

```
iv = new ChildInitAndVisit()
println "ChildInitAndVisit - calling init() -> ${iv.init()}"
println "ChildInitAndVisit - calling visit() -> ${iv.visit()}"

v = new ChildVisitOnly()
println "ChildVisitOnly - calling visit() -> ${v.visit()}"
```

I would expect to see:

```
ChildVisitOnly - calling visit() -> GrandParent init, Parent init, Child visit
```

as the output of the last println. Instead I see:

```
ChildVisitOnly - calling visit() -> GrandParent init, Child visit
```

This is in contrast to the behaviour of the ChildInitAndVisit class and different to the behaviour under older versions of Groovy - I checked 2.3.4.

Is this a Groovy bug? Or should I be doing something different?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it is a bug. `super.init()` in ChildVisitOnly must call Parent#init().

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is [multi-methods](http://groovy-lang.org/differences.html#_multi_methods) (runtime/dynamic dispatch) behavior of Groovy. At runtime, `init()` from `GrandParent` is used instead of `init()` from `Parent`.

One way to use it the Java way (compile time dispatch) is to use `@CompileStatic` on `ChildVisitOnly` class.

```
@CompileStatic
class ChildVisitOnly extends Parent { 

    String visit() { 
        return super.init() + "Child visit" 
    } 
}
```

Above would give the result you expect.

Another approach would be to use `init()` or `this.init()` in `ChildVisitOnly` explicitly instead of `@CompileStatic` to force the use of `init()` from `Parent`.

```
class ChildVisitOnly extends Parent { 

    String visit() { 
        return init() + "Child visit" 
    } 
}
```

This obviously deviates from the behavior from Groovy 2.3.4 but I am yet to find a related issue which focuses on this difference. I am curious to see if anybody else can point me to a defect due to which the behavior changed. :)

Comment: Instance based multimethods as Groovy is using means that methods from sub classes become visible in the scope of the parent class when considering a method call in the parent class, while working on an instance of the child class. but multimethods do not override methods in the Java sense. Which means, the init method in ChildVisitOnly must be from Parent, not from GrandParent. Groovy simply fails to understand, that if you write `super.init()` and do not override the init() method that it should not take the parent class of the declaring class of the init method